# Blackberry pixel-specific animated focus scrolling

Tags: blackberry, scroll, focus

Suppose I have a VFM full of both focusable and non-focusable fields. Since most of them are spread out far apart, the movement from one focused field to another is jerky at best, even with NullFields in between. In other words, it just sets the current y position to the next focused field without smoothly scrolling the screen.

What I want to achieve is to be able to scroll at a fixed rate between fields, so it it doesn't just focus from one to another that instantaneously. After reading up on how to do this, it is a matter of overriding moveFocus and setting it via a TimerTask from an accessor method to set moveFocus, as per this [link](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/65285-scrollingf-issue-help.html). However, I haven't seen a practical implementation of how to do this, complete with the routines that are called in the TimerTask's thread.

Is there any way to achieve this type of behavior?

Comment: Bumping this since it was almost a month and still no response. Any takers?